# Multiple directives [ngController, ...] asking for new/isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I have the following (https://jsfiddle.net/hhgqup4f/5/):

```
<div parent parent-model="vm.model1" ng-controller="Controller as vm">
   Parent
</div>
```

And the controller is:

```
app.controller("Controller", Controller);

function Controller() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.model1 = "My Model 1";
  vm.model2 = "My Model 2";
}
```

And then I have a directive as follows:

```
app.directive("parent", parent);

function parent() {

  var parent = {
    controller: ["$scope", controller],
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      model: "="
    }
  };

  return parent;

  function controller($scope) { 
    console.log($scope.model);
  } 

}
```

With parent-model="vm.model1" I am trying to say which property from the controller should be used by the directive. But when I do console.log($scope.model) in the directive I get the error:

```
"Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngController, parent (module: app)] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div parent="" parent-model="vm.model1" ng-controller="Controller as vm">
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Error clearing stating that, you can not create have two directive which are creating different scope. like ngController has `scope: true` & `parent` directive has `scope: { ..  }`

Comment: So how can "say" to directive parent which property to use from parent controller through an attribute? I would like to use that property, and only that one, inside the directive

Comment: You could shift `Controller as vm` inside directive, I'm not sure that will be valid in your case..

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error ...

> `"Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngController, parent (module: app)] asking for new/isolated scope on: <div parent="" parent-model="vm.model1" ng-controller="Controller as vm">`

... is quite illustrative as AngularJS doesn't allow multiple directives (*on the same DOM level*) to create their own **isolate** scopes.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir), this restriction is imposed in order to prevent *collision or unsupported configuration* of the `$scope` objects.

Normally a directive is supplied with an isolate `scope` with an intention towards *componentization* or *reuse* of some logic/action attached to the DOM.

Therefore, it makes sense that two reusable components cannot be merged together to produce a combined effect (at least in AngularJS).

### Solution

Change your directive usage such that it is *supplied* with the required properties from its immediate parent (*which in this case is the `ngController` directive*).

```
<div ng-controller="Controller as vm">
  <div parent parent-model="vm.model1"></div>
</div>
```

Similarly, you can access the passed properties to the isolate scope of the directive in their *normalized* format:

```
app.directive('parent', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
       parentModel: '='  // property passed from the parent scope
    },
    controller: function($scope){
       console.log($scope.parentModel); 
    }
  };
});
```

### [*Demo*](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/uye9ww3r/2/)

---

### Directive to Directive Communication

Two or more directives with isolate scopes, as mentioned earlier, can't be used on the same DOM element. However, it is possible for one of the directives to have an isolated scope. Other directives, in this case, can communicate if required by *`require`ing* its controller as such:

```
<div dir-isolate dir-sibling></div>

...

.directive('dirIsolate', function(){
  return {
    scope: {},
    controller: function(){
      this.askSomething = function(){
         return 'Did you ask for something?';
      };
    }
  };
})
.directive('dirSibling', function(){
  return {
    require: 'dirIsolate', // here is the trick
    link: function(scope, iElement, attrs, dirSiblingCtrl){ // required controller passed to the link function as fourth argument
       console.log(dirSiblingCtrl.askSomething());
    }
  };
});
```